# XML design for table data

Tags: xml, data-structures, xmltable

I am looking for good practice design to store table data

```
x | 1 | 2 
___________
1 |4.3|0.1
2 |7.3|4.3
```

in XML format.

Comment: Can you provide any more context for your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
  <Table name="myTable">
            <Row id="1">
                <x> 1 </x>
                <1> 4.3 </1>
                <2> 0.1 </2>
                </Row>
            <Row id="2">
                <x> 2 </x>
                <1> 7.2 </1>
                <2> 4.3 </2>
            </Row>
        </Table>
```

Comment: would you please add the header, just for the completeness of the answer.